# Sharing large pandas DataFrame with multiprocessing for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Using Python 2.7 on a Windows machine, I have a large `pandas` DataFrame (about 7 million rows and 20+ columns) from a SQL query that I'd like to filter by looping through IDs then run calculations on the resulting filtered data.  I'd also like to do this in parallel.

I know that if I try to do this with standard methods from the `multiprocessing` package in Windows, each process will generate a new instance of that large DataFrame for its own use and my memory will be eaten up.  So I'm trying to use information I've read on [remote managers](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2007/10/01/multiprocessing/) to make my DataFrame a proxy object and share that across each process but I'm struggling to make it work.

My code is below, and I can get it to work on a single for loop no problem, but again the memory gets eaten up if I make it a parallel process:

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas
import pyodbc

def download(args):
    """pydobc code to download data from sql database"""

def calc(dataset, index):
    filter_data = dataset[dataset['ID'] == index]
    """run calculations on filtered DataFrame"""
    """append results to local csv"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_1 = download(args_1)
    data_2 = download(args_2)
    all_data = data_1.append(data_2) #Append downloaded DataFrames into one

    unique_id = pandas.unique(all_data['ID'])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    [pool.apply_async(calc, args=(all_data, x) ) for x in unique_id ]
```

Comment: Have a look at Dask for out of core computing: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Alexander checking it now, mulling through it but seems promising.  Can you pass multiple arguments into one of your graph functions?  Having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : "***Sharing*** large pandas DataFrame **with multiprocessing** for loop in Python ?"

While there are tools to share some data in the **`multiprocessing`** module, the actual use will here actually represent an ***anti-pattern*** to the presented will to operate this, for performance reasons, inside a `Pool`-instance, in a *"just"*-**`[CONCURRENT]`**-fashion.

---

### Why?

You spend immense costs on moving the filtering into a `Pool`-of-independent ( *"just"*-**`[CONCURRENT]`** ) workers, yet each of them is waiting to get served by, again the central GIL-lock, which turns the `Manager`'s work again into a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** and even worse, being RAM I/O-bound, the performance suffocation from having no free access to RAM, goes principally in a wrong direction ).

---

### THE ECONOMY OF [ADD-ON COSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427809) v/s THE TRAP of [AMDAHL's LAW](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) :

The speed of burning the money ( add-on costs ), that are not visible from a few SLOC-s can be ( and often ***is***) way higher, than any ( only potential, until well engineered, tuned and validated ) in-vivo performance benefit, from operating several lines of code-execution in a *"just"*-**`[CONCURRENT]`** ( the harder for a True-**`[PARALLEL]`** ) fashion.